# What type of variable is intent.slots.myIntent.value in the source code of a lambda AWS JS

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm doing a skill in the Alexa development console.

An intent within the skill is as follows:

**activates the output {mySlot}** where **mySlot** is of type **AMAZON.NUMBER**

I have taken a lambda function provided by the manufacturer of a microntroller from an example.

This function is a JS file where I have written a function for the aforementioned intent as follows:

```js
function setMyOutPut(intent, session, callback)
{
  ...
  const desiredState = intent.slots.mySlot.value;
  if ((desiredState === 1))
  {
    powerOn = 1;
  }
  else if ((desiredState === 2))
  {
    powerOn = 2;
  }
  else if ((desiredState === 3))
  {
    powerOn = 3;
  }
  else
  {
    speechOutput = "There are only three outputs to activate";
    repromptText = "I did not understand the exit number, please try again';
    callback(sessionAttributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
  }
  ...

}
```

When from Alexa I execute the Skill and the intent, when I say "activates the output one", a confirmation Intent is executed in which Alexa responds "The output has been activated correctly".

But if I say, for example "activate the output seven", in the same way it responds that it has been activated correctly.

Or there are times when I say "activates the output three" and the else is produced and it answers "There are only three outputs to activate".

So what I suspect is that intent.slots.mySlot.value is not a numeric variable.

Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: Try console.log( typeof desiredState ) this should show you the type

Comment: In your code, in the `else` statement, your `repormptText` variable has mismatching quotes. It starts with a double quote and ends with a single quote. I'm not sure if you typed this out to the page and therefore it's just a typo or if it's like that in your current code.  But that will definitely cause some problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's a typo

Comment: To observe how the skill is interpreting what you're testing with, you can try using the developer console test tab and try with numbers and strings like "1", "2" but also "one", "two" and check the json input (user request) to see what the skill is taking.